# Database schema to store branches/merges in a dependency network

Tags: mysql, database, recursion, network-programming, normalization

I love the nested-set model for storing hierarchical data, and I'd like to find a similar model for storing task dependencies in a project management application.

**Issue 1: Unsustainable complexity of recursive database queries / function calls:**

Right now, I have a simple m:n table that stores Task/Blocker pairs, but looping through the data is unoptimized at best, and a recursive nightmare at worst.  I'd like to limit database calls in a tight loop, and--with a "normal" tree--I'd use a nested set to accomplish this.

**Issue 2: multiple inheritance, multiple descendance**

The reason I can't use a tree is that this set contains not only branches, but also *merges.* Some tasks have multiple "parent nodes"--if you will--multiple tasks that have to be completed before it can start.  It seems similar to how I assume SVN or Git must work to store versioning information.

**I want to run queries like:**

- Get all tasks, recursively, dependent on a specific task (top-down traversal)
- Add all time estimates for a specific task and all its dependencies (bottom-up traversal)
- Constrain list of potential dependencies for a task to logical options (can't depend on itself, in a loop)

**Possible options so far:**

- Bight the bullet and deal with the complexity
- Index all the sequences ("routes", if you will, to finish all tasks)--still unsure how to store this
- Store both top-down nested sets and bottom-up nested sets
- Pray that some StackOverflow guru knows more than I do on the subject

What's the best way (and how sure are you that it will work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with tasks and task_relationships tables.
Use the task_relationships table for multiple parents or children.
task relationship has parent and child fields both are id's in the tasks table.

Comment: That's exactly where I started.  Is this as far as it goes, or is there a next step for optimizing queries against the hierarchy?

Comment: next step might be denormalization.  Which has upsides (performance) and downsides (consistancy, duplication)

Comment: Ok, so I could keep the relationships normalized (per your answer), but cache some implied relationships (a denormalized representation) for performance purposes in querying the data.  That makes sense. Thanks!